# I am trying to figure out how to create a clean up function as I keep getting an error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, use-effect

I am trying to figure out how to create a clean up function as I keep getting an error, if I remove "comments" from the useEffect dependencies, the error goes away, but then the app doesn't update in realtime, which is a problem. If anyone has worked with React and the realtime database or even Firestore and have any ideas on what I should do please let me know.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

import User from '../assets/images/user.svg';

import { AuthContext } from '../helpers/firebaseAuth';
import firebase from '../helpers/Firebase';
import Loading from '../helpers/Loading';

export const Comments = ({ match, history }) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

    const slug = match.params.slug;

    const {...currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = () => {
            const data = firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${slug}/comments`)

            data.once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot) {
                    let comments = [];
                    const snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
                    for (let comment in snapshotVal) {
                        comments.push(snapshotVal[comment]);
                    }
                    setComments(comments);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            });
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [slug, comments])


    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    };

    const postComment = (values) => {

        console.log(!!currentUser.currentUser)

        if (!!currentUser.currentUser) {
            const comment = {
                commentText: values.commentText,
                commentCreator: currentUser.currentUser.displayName,
                currentUserId: currentUser.currentUser.uid,
            }

            const postRef = firebase.database().ref(`posts/${slug}/comments`);
            postRef.push(comment);

            reset();
        } else {
            toast.error('You are not authenticated ');
        }
    };

    const deleteComment = () => {

        console.log(comments[0].commentUserId);
        console.log(currentUser.currentUser.uid);

        if (currentUser.currentUser.uid === comments[0].commentUserId) {
            console.log('correct');
        }

        const key = firebase.database().ref(`posts/${slug}/comments`).once('value');

        key.then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    };

    const back = () => {
        history.push('./');
    };

    return (
        <div className='main' style={{ maxWidth: '600px' }}>
            <div className='see-user-comments' onClick={back} style={{ cursor: 'pointer', height: '50px' }}>
                Commenting on the post: {slug}
            </div>
            <div className='see-user-comments' style={{ padding: '10px 0' }}>
                <div>
                    <img src={User} alt='Profile' style={{ width: '30px' }} />
                    <span className='usertag-span'>{currentUser.displayName}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(postComment)}>
                        <textarea 
                            name='commentText'
                            rows='3'
                            style={{ margin: '10px 0' }}
                            placeholder='Add to the conversation!'
                            ref={register} 
                        /> 
                        <span style={{ width: '90%' }}>
                            <button>Comment</button>
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            {comments.map((comment, index) =>
            <div key={index} className='see-user-comments' style={{ padding: '15px 0' }}>
                <div style={{ height: '30px' }}>
                    <img src={User} alt='Profile' style={{ width: '30px' }} />
                    <div style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyItems: 'center' }}>
                        <span className='usertag-span'>{comment.commentCreator}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span className='commentText-span'>{comment.commentText}
                    { !!currentUser?.currentUser?.uid === comments[0].commentUserId ?
                        (<button onClick={deleteComment}>Delete</button>) : null 
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Comments;
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify anything I'm as newbie as most of you could probably already tell

Comment: Please include the error message you are getting and the line it occurs.

Comment: See if this article helps you https://dev.to/pallymore/clean-up-async-requests-in-useeffect-hooks-90h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the error in question, I can only assume it's because using the following pattern causes an infinite loop because the effect is re-triggered every time `count` changes:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => setCount(count + 1), [count]);
```

When you add `comments` to your effect, you are doing the same thing.

To solve this, you must change your effect to rely on Firebase's realtime events to update your comments array instead. This can be as simple as changing `once('value').then((snap) => {...})` to `on('value', (snap) => {...});`. Because this is now a realtime listener, you must also return a function that unsubscribes the listener from inside your `useEffect` call. The least amount of code to do this correctly is:

```js
const [postId, setPostId] = useState('post001');

useEffect(() => {
    const postRef = firebase.database().ref('posts').child(postId);
    const listener = postRef.on(
        'value',
        postSnapshot => {
            const postData = postSnapshot.val();
            // ... update UI ...
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Failed to get post', err);
            // ... update UI ...
        }
    )

    return () => postRef.off('value', listener);

}, [postId]);
```

Applying these changes to your code (as well as some QoL improvements) yields:

```js
const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

const slug = match.params.slug;

const { ...authContext } = useContext(AuthContext); // renamed: currentUser -> authContext (misleading & ambiguous)

const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

let _postCommentHandler, _deleteCommentHandler;

useEffect(() => {
    // don't call this data - it's not the data but a reference to it - always call it `somethingRef` instead
    const postCommentsRef = firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${slug}/comments`);

    // create realtime listener
    const listener = postCommentsRef.on(
        'value',
        querySnapshot => {
            let _comments = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(commentSnapshot => {
                const thisComment = commentSnapshot.val();
                thisComment.key = commentSnapshot.key; // store the key for delete/edit operations
                _comments.push(thisComment);
            });
            setComments(_comments);
            setLoading(false);
        },
        err => {
            console.log(`Error whilst getting comments for post #${slug}`, err);
            // TODO: handle error
        });

    // update new comment handler
    _postCommentHandler = (formData) => {
        console.log({
            isLoggedIn: !!authContext.currentUser
        });

        if (!authContext.currentUser) {
            toast.error('You are not authenticated ');
            return;
        }

        const newComment = {
            commentText: formData.commentText, // suggested: commentText -> content
            commentCreator: authContext.currentUser.displayName, // suggested: commentCreator -> author
            currentUserId: authContext.currentUser.uid, // suggested: commentUserId -> authorId
        }

        postCommentsRef.push(newComment)
            .then(() => {
                // commented successfully
                reset(); // reset form completely
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`Error whilst posting new comment`, err);
                // TODO: handle error
                reset({ commentText: formData.commentText }) // reset form, but leave comment as-is
            })
    }

    // update delete handler
    _deleteCommentHandler = () => {
        if (!comments || !comments[0]) {
            console.log('Nothing to delete');
            return;
        }

        const commentToDelete = comments[0];

        console.log({
            commentUserId: commentToDelete.commentUserId,
            currentUser: authContext.currentUser.uid
        });

        if (authContext.currentUser.uid !== commentToDelete.commentUserId) {
            toast.error('That\'s not your comment to delete!');
            return;
        }

        postCommentsRef.child(commentToDelete.key)
            .remove()
            .then(() => {
                // deleted successfully
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`Error whilst deleting comment #${commentToDelete.key}`, err);
                // TODO: handle error
            });
    };

    // return listener cleanup function
    return () => postCommentsRef.off('value', listener);
}, [slug]);

const postComment = (values) => _postCommentHandler(values);
const deleteComment = () => _deleteCommentHandler();
```

Because I renamed `currentUser` to `authContext`, this will also need updating:

```html
<div>
    <img src={User} alt='Profile' style={{ width: '30px' }} />
    <span className='usertag-span'>{authContext?.currentUser?.displayName}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I did ```return () => postCommentsRef.off();``` instead of ```return () => postCommentsRef.off(listener);``` and everything works

Comment: Thanks for the reply samthecodingman, you helped much out so much (also with things I didn't even realize and know that I needed help on) and yeah I really need to work on my code and naming stuff. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ah that was my bad. It should have been `postCommentsRef.off('value', listener);`, which I would recommend using because `postCommentsRef.off()` may lead to unintentional side effects because it will cancel all listeners on that location - even those outside the scope of your component.